# how to write this sql command in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to run this query with Laravel 4.2 but I'm unsure how to implement it.  Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?  Thanks!

```
select * from (select * from `t_quotation_revises` ORDER BY id DESC) AS x GROUP BY `t_quotation_id`
```

Comment: How to implememt this sql command in laravel 4.2 syntax....

Comment: And you found nothing? Have you searched the Laravel documentation? This is an easy enough task to get started with and it looks like you just want to skip the work part and get the solution from someone else.

Comment: Laravel's ORM is called Eloquent. Here is the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent It should give you enough information to build your query. The only way to learn properly is by reading the docs and trying it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select * from `t_quotation_revises` ORDER BY id DESC) AS x GROUP BY `t_quotation_id`
```

This above query would be written as in laravel 4.2 like :

```
$reviseQuotationArr = DB::table(DB::raw('(select * from `t_quotation_revises`  ORDER BY id DESC)AS x'))
                                    ->groupBy('t_quotation_id')
                                    ->get();
```